# What is the place called where cheese is aged?

Tags: cheese, language

When cheddar cheese is made, it is kept on shelves in a climate controlled place and each wheel is turned over once per week. What is the place called where the cheese is kept during this aging process?

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there's a specific name for it.

I found [a book](https://books.google.com/books?id=oLbqAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=cheese%20aging%20space&source=bl&ots=SrPa1vuVAE&sig=DmMbdyELA4_IveXea5hLgV01WOU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN5MO0r5_ZAhUJR6wKHSmiBYgQ6AEIigEwEg#v=onepage&q=cheese%20aging%20space&f=false) that simply refers to it as an "aging space/room".

> ### The Aging Room: The "Big Three" Design Issues
>
> When designing an aging space, there are three main factors to consider: temperature, humidity, and air (both air exchange and movement). Each of these factors will be influenced by the volume and type of cheese being aged; your area's native influences (weather and soil/earth stability and properties; also if your building is underground); and the building structure and size.
> <sub>The Small-Scale Cheese Business: The Complete Guide to Running a Successful Farmstead Creamery p. 126</sub>

Around the web, I've seen it referred to as a "cheese cave", which refers to the historical habit of using caves for aging cheese.

1. [How to Make a Cheese “Cave”](http://blog.cheesemaking.com/how-to-make-cheese-cave/) - This is a guide on aging cheese in a refrigerator.
2. [Crown Finish Caves](http://www.crownfinishcaves.com/) - A cheese aging facility in Brooklyn, NY.
3. Wegman's Food Market [opened a "cheese cave" in 2014](https://www.wegmans.com/about-us/inside-our-stores/for-the-love-of-cheese.html).

For a similar reason, I've seen a smaller number of references to "cheese cellar".